# Uncaught Error: The send transactions "from" field must be defined!

Tags: web3js

I am trying to send payments to another account  but  I keep getting this  message

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
    try {
      await ethereum.enable();
      initPayButton()
    } catch (err) {
      $('#status').html('User denied account access', err)
    }
  } else if (window.web3) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
    initPayButton()
  } else {
    $('#status').html('No Metamask (or other Web3 Provider) installed')
  }
})

const initPayButton = () => {
  $('.pay-button').click(() => {
    // paymentAddress is where funds will be send to
    const paymentAddress = '0x5EF7395FE1de8cbCA95df3B328Db3Ffc3F7727b7'
    const amountEth = '1'

    web3.eth.sendTransaction({
      from:web3.eth.accounts.wallet,
      to: paymentAddress,
      value: web3.utils.toWei(amountEth, 'ether')
    }, (err, transactionId) => {
      if  (err) {
        console.log('Payment failed', err)
        $('#status').html('Payment failed')
      } else {
        console.log('Payment successful', transactionId)
        $('#status').html('Payment successful')
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: @Ismael: *"Ii am trying"* → *"I am trying"*

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the value of *web3.eth.accounts.wallet*. I think this is giving an undefined value.

```
console.log(web3.eth.accounts.wallet)
```

See if it is giving a wallet address or not. In some cases, it is not able to fetch accounts.